# Why does storing a function call to pop not return the last item when the list instance is modified?

Tags: python, list

I have the following code:

```
 d = [1,2,3,4] 
 dpop = d.pop 
 d = ["A","B","C"]
 dpop() # return 4 
 d.pop() #return C
```

Why does the list defined in my first list still exist, and where does it exist?

Comment: Variable names in Python are just labels you stick on objects.  They do not refer to any fixed space in memory, like in C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first list exists because a reference to it is kept by the method object to which `dpop` is pointing.

Essentially, what you've done is this:

```
dpop = [1,2,3,4].pop
```

The instance of the `pop` method which you've stored in `dpop` is associated with the instance of the list that you initially had (and you can find it in `dpop.__self__`).

Comment: `dpop` is a bound method.  The original list can be accessed via `dpop.__self__`.

Comment: Amber, @SvenMarnach Nice interesting answer!

Answer (score 2):

You keep a reference to a `boundmethod` object, which itself keeps a reference to it's instance. cf https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod for more on what a Python method is really.